# How to keep image fixed at bottom right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a footer/navigation fixed to the bottom right corner of the screen so when you scroll down it will always be visible, and when you pull the bottom right of the browser to make it bigger it will stay fixed in the corner. I would also like it to scale smaller when you make the browser smaller. I've figured a way to do this in the top left corner but not the right.

I have tried

```
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 right:0:
```

however this doesn't seem to be working. I am left with a mysterious space between the edge of the page and my image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n1tO.jpg) (doing a negative margin on the div does not erase this space) I also do not want to affix this as a background image because I eventually want to make it an image map.

sorry if this is confusing! I am still a newb at this.

```
    <div id="footer">
<img src= "images/swirlfooter.png" width="75%" height="75%">
</div>
```

is the width and height the culprit of the space? if so how would i fix that? just create the image in the exact size i need it to be?

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, try to set the width and height by the footer and not the img.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need a fixed position, if you don't want it to move while scrolling.

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:75%;
}
#footer img {width:100%;}
```

And to clear the margins :

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Be careful, the `position:fixed`, unfortunatly doesn't work with safari on iOS (iPhones, iPads...)

You can see a **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvSCn/1/)**.

**Edit**

Another solution is to put the img in background of the footer, like this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/FvSCn/3/)** :

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    width:75%;
    height:75%;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/FZoaLd0.jpg) no-repeat bottom right;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Position absolute will move with scroll. What you need is `positon:fixed;`

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0:
}
```

Comment: Did you try placing the property on the footer?

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: fixed;`.

You also might want to try clearing the body and HTML margins:

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Is it withing any parent containers that have position set to `position: relative;`?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position:fixed;
```

Instead of `absolute`.

Fixed will keep it always at the bottom right of the window.
Absolute changes as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="class-name">
   <img src="images/image-name.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.class-name {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -50px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -120px;
    z-index: 11000;
}
div.class-name img{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Change `margin-top` according to your image height.